# Azure Devops pipeline triggering twice with Build Validation

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have created a pipeline in my repository which is used to validate code by executing unit tests for code that is being pushed to `features/*` branches. The same pipeline is used as Build validation pipeline set as Branch Policy on the develop branch to validate incoming PRs. This is the trigger of the pipeline.

```
# pipeline.yml
trigger:
  batch: false
  branches:
    include:
      - features/*
```

However we have come across the following condition: Given an open PR from `refs/heads/features/azure-pipelines -> refs/heads/develop` we push a commit on the `features/azure-pipelines` branch.

This causes the pipeline to trigger twice. To my understanding one of the runs is due to the trigger of the pipeline (The one marked as Individual CI on the screenshot) and the second run is due to branch policy trying to validate code being pushed onto the open PR to develop. (The PR Automated)

[image]

Is there any way to disable one of the executions since it's essentially a duplicate? I was maybe looking for a way to retrieve open PRs and abort execution of a pipeline for `Individual CI` if there is an open PR for a branch but I am not sure that's the best way around that and I am looking for options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to disable one of the executions since it's essentially a duplicate?

As we know, we could not disable the Build validation pipeline set as Branch Policy on the develop branch to validate incoming PRs unless we cancel the Build validation.

For your situation, you could try to include `[skip ci]` in the commit message or description of the HEAD commit to make the Azure Pipelines skip running CI when you plan to merge the features branch to the develop branch.

You could check the document [Skipping CI for individual commits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#skipping-ci-for-individual-commits) for some more details.

Comment: This is not the most elegant solution since we preferred a solution that was automatic but it's getting the job done so I am accepting this.

Answer (score 2):

You can set

```yaml
trigger: none
```

This way only the branch policy will trigger the pipeline.

Comment: Hmm, this way the branch will only be build once there is a pull request open. This is in my opinion too late, the branch should be build without a pr, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
trigger:
- master #probably name of your default branch
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/sprint-146-update#avoid-triggering-multiple-ci-builds-for-pull-requests :

> The YAML build templates included with Azure Pipelines were configured to trigger builds for any branch within a repository. This included pull request topic branches. As a result, two builds were triggered when pull requests were created. One build for the pull request branch in response to the continuous integration trigger, and a second build for the pull request branch in response to the pull request trigger.

> By using the YAML snippet below, the built-in YAML templates will be configured to trigger a continuous integration build only for the master branch. New pull requests will still build using the pull request trigger. For more details, see the documentation for build pipeline triggers .

Answer (score 0):

Here it depends if they does the same. You can have conditional checks in the pipeline which does a different things for PR and CI runs. However, I'm pretty sure that this is not possible, because one is defined on the YAML and the second on the Azure DevOps portal. So even if you disnle PR trigger here in YAML, a branch policy still runs a PR. And you can specify antyhing in YAML to block branch policy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. To prevent this, in your `trigger.branches.include` you only need to put the build branches, not the branches used in pull requests (like `features/*`).

```yaml
# pipelines.yml
trigger:
  batch: false
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - dev

stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
      template: unit-test-jobs.yml
  - stage: deploy
    condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
    jobs: ...
```

This way, your pipeline will run due pull requests and when new commits are pushed to your branches (`master` and `dev` in the example above).

Comment: In my opinion is the big downside, that features/* branches will not  build until you open up a pull request.

Comment: @MarkusSchulte this works fine in my team. We have many devs and we don't want to run pipelines in "wip commits". Some devs makes 20+ commits before open a pull request. It would be a waste of resources on unnecessary runs.